# How to set a property of each object inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array as example:

```
array = [{id:3},{id:2},{id:4}]
```

I want to loop through this array of objects, and make each "id" from each object equal to its index position inside of the array, to make something like this:

```
array =[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2}]
```

Any idea of how can I do this?

Thank you all for the attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using forEach metohd will loop to every object in the array then to change a property value of an object to the index of the element you must pass the object and its index as the second args then equate it to the object property.

```
let array = [{id:3},{id:2},{id:4}] 
 array.forEach((item, index) => { 
 item.id = index 
})
```

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I'm sorry. I'm still learning just started answering questions. Thanks for your comment anyway! Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `map` would work:

```js
const array = [{id:3},{id:2},{id:4}];
const newArray = array.map((e, i) => ({ id: i }));
console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you want to keep all other properties the same (if you have multiple properties):

```js
const array = [{id:3, name: "A"},{id:2, name: "B"},{id:4, name: "C"}];
const newArray = array.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, id: i }));
console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can loop over an array with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].id = i;
}
```

Comment: When I try this approach, it gives me an "Cannot set property 'id' of undefined"  :(

Comment: Then your array might have holes or you are iterating over it incorrectly.